# Kotlin Arrow lens for Option

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to use Arrow optics for a class with an `Option` field. The following code works fine:

```
@optics
data class TestClass(val opt: String) { companion object }

val tc = TestClass("Hello")
val tc2 = TestClass.opt.set(tc, "def")
```

but the (similar looking) following code doesn't:

```
@optics
data class TestClass(val opt: Option<String>) { companion object }

val tc = TestClass(Some("Hello"))
val tc2 = TestClass.opt.set(tc, None)
```

It looks like the last `set` is expecting a `String`, not an `Option<String>`. How can I use lenses to clear the `Optional`?

(I realize in this case I can just use `copy()` or even do a manual copy, but I have a real situation where a similar class is deeply nested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: `@optics` will also generate an `optionFieldName` lens, e.g.

```
@optics
data class TestClass(val opt: Option<String>) { companion object }

val tc = TestClass(Some("Hello"))
val tc2 = TestClass.optionOpt.set(tc, None)
```